# Finding similarity dissimilarity between different groups of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning

Suppose I need to combine or group together set of vectors in one area and another group in other areas, however I need to place these groups in a plot so they are scattered in the screen per similarity or dissimilarity.

-the vectors are actually word2vec, therefore each group is sentence
- I thought of adding individual vectors in each group, (word vectors) but how it will represent similar words in different groups.

Attached is an conceptual graph of what am trying to do.

[conceptual graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5blR.png)

1. OK, let say I have Group 1: consists of 3 vectors, Group 2: 4
   vectors, Group 3: 2 vectors. between group 1 and 2 for example, 1
   vector is similar, now I need to find similarities between the
   groups as I need the vectors to remain enclosed in groups. Hope the
   image attached can help

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are asking. Can you please rephrase?

Comment: Hi @Ertxiem, I just updated the question, please see bullet point OK.